# QGIS styling of two data values

Tags: qgis, style

I have a situation that requires the displaying of the results by precinct of an election between two of the candidates. For each precinct I would like to have two colors filling the polygon proportional to the total vote count. Also displaying the numeric count in text. Does anybody know a strategy that will achieve this result?

Comment: Interesting... I'm expecting for someone to solve this in QGIS

Comment: Do you want a single colour which is a **proportional blend** of two colours (e.g. candidates are Yellow and Blue, where Yellow =100% candidate 1, Blue=100% candidate 2, Green is 50% each)? Something like this can work well but is better done with equal-area cartograms rather than choropleth.

Comment: That sounds messy, especially if some polygons are small and can't really be seen... could it work to instead show the polygons using a pie chart symbol with the proportions showing there instead?

Comment: This thread has an answer:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216297/proportional-coloring-within-polygon-for-multiple-variables